# MaxHeight of ChildWindow changed to Infinity after calling show() in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

My xaml code is below.

```
<ChildWindow x:Class="Donas.Client.Common.MessageWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Width="450" Height="180" MaxHeight="600" FontFamily="Malgun Gothic" FontSize="12"
       Title="Title">
```

Although I set max height to 600px, max height changed to Infinity after calling `Show()` method. I noticed this from debugging. I want to know why the max height change to infinity and how to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Try settings the max height in code behind just below or above where you called the Show() method. Maybe your xaml code having sort of error for setting it..

Comment: Setting the max height before calling show() may have no effect because the max height is already set in xaml. So I've tried setting the max height after calling show() method, it works. But the max height of the childwindow's background is also shortened.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some sort of panel in your UI that is growing the height? If so, try setting the maxheight within that element. It tends to grow things unexpectedly.